# Why do people say 慢点儿阿("man dianer a") when you leave their shop?

Tags: meaning, expressions

When you leave a shop, you often hear the shopkeeper saying something like "man dianer a", which sounds like 慢点儿阿 (something parents say to their kids to get them to walk more slowly [even if they never listen]).

It's quite possible I'm mishearing what they're saying.  It really is an everyday thing to say, and I've heard it in lots of different and unrelated shops.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`慢走` is a polite thing to say usually used for someone who is leaving, has two implicit meaning:

1. I don't want you to leave, so please leave slowly, so I can stay a little longer with you.
2. Don't hurry, take care.

`慢点儿` has the same meaning, but not as formal as `慢走`, and sounds more affable.

Answer (score 5):

You heard it right and all above answers are correct. But I'll just translate 慢点儿啊 in this context (as a lot more cases) as "take care".

Answer (score 3):

I've heard 慢走 plenty of times and 慢点儿 seems very similar. It’s just a polite thing to say that means something like 一路平安. They don't literally mean to walk slower.

Answer (score 3):

You were totally hearing it right. It is "慢点儿啊". Sometimes people may rush and get into trouble, so don't rush, take it slow and you will get back safely.

I would assume you heard this in the northern part of China. It's not just shops, people would say the same to their guests when they leave.

However, it's just a saying, being polite. Like in the UK, people would say "You all right?", that's just like Chinese say "吃了没?". Do they really care about your well being or your empty belly?

Answer (score 0):

What you hear is correct, but its has a little different. When a parent says to a child, slow down. It means letting the kids out of the house and being safe. It's a caring one. Statement ，When you come out of a store. That boss usually speaks to u slowly. What he means is a polite expression. I'm a Chinese

Answer (score -1):

It's also some kind of subtle joke, since when counting the money paid for the goods at the counter, the shopkeeper may realize that the customer is getting away having paid less than what was expected, so in that case it would be said say something like: "Slowly! Slow! Where are you going?" (even if the situation was the opposite). It is also a way to get eh customer to take a second look at the merchandise and therefore to gain an additional opportunity to make an extra last-minute sale. This kind of tongue-in cheek humour is tipical in bargain-intensive environments where prices are not fixed but negotiated, and shops cluttered with shelves.

Answer (score -1):

慢点儿 means take care , watching your way.